# Python: how to get subclass's new attributes name in base class's method?

Tags: python, attributes, subclass

I want to put all attribute names in SubClass to a list, I want to do that in Base class. How can I do that?
My method now is:

```
class Base():
    def __init__(self):
        # print SubClass' new attribues' names ('aa' and 'bb' for example)
        for attr in dir(self):
            if not hasattr(Base, attr):
                print attr

class SubClass(Base):
    aa = ''
    bb = ''
```

is there a better way to do that ?

---

Thanks for any help.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish actually?

Comment: sorry for the confusing, I have edited the question. I want to make some class like google's db api, when I define a new subclass of the db.Model Class, db.Model will know the attribue of the SubClass are the colum names of the database.

Comment: You don't want `dir(self)` but `dir(self.__class__)`, otherwise you'll get instance attributes (defined in a subclass' `__init__` for example) not just attributes of the class. Otherwise, your version is essentially the same as mine, mine is just a bit shorter (and, arguable, clearer, as `-` means difference and that's what you want).

Comment: What @JohnZ meant what _why_ you think you need to know the subclass' added attributes in the base class. It doesn't make sense -- the base class shouldn't know anything about the subclass, really.

Comment: thank you @agf , yes your method is the same, and a lot of better, it is what I want. but why in my test, dir(self) == dir(self.__class__) seems always True? they all don't have instance attributes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the @JohnZwinck suggested in a comment, you're almost certainly making a design mistake if you need to do this. Without more info, however, we can't diagnose the problem.

This seems the simplest way to do what you want:

```
class Base(object):
    cc = '' # this won't get printed
    def __init__(self):
        # print SubClass' new attribues' names ('aa' and 'bb' for example)
        print set(dir(self.__class__)) - set(dir(Base))

class SubClass(Base):
    aa = ''
    bb = ''


foo = SubClass()
# set(['aa', 'bb'])
```

The reason you need `self.__class__` instead of `self` to test for new attributes is this:

```
class Base(object):
    cc = ''
    def __init__(self):
        print set(dir(self)) - set(dir(Base))
        # print SubClass' new attribues' names ('aa' and 'bb' for example)

class SubClass(Base):
    def __init__(self):
        self.dd = ''
        super(SubClass, self).__init__()
    aa = ''
    bb = ''


foo = SubClass()
# set(['aa', 'dd', 'bb'])
```

If you want the difference between the classes **as defined**, you need to use `__class__`. If you don't, you'll get **different results depending on when you check for new attributes**.

Comment: thank you, thank you very much @agf , I've seen the difference between dir(self) and dir(self.__class__), I don't know why they appear the same before, but this time they are defferent. thanks again.